# Batch Pipeline to sync contact

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

Information and it is not getting synchronized.

`DEBUG [Data Exchange] Cannot resolve entity model from location or entity model is null. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Contact Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: 00fcd89b-21a1-4694-be3d-07ccf3cf84d8)`

Did anybody encounter a similar situation and how do we analyze this?

To add on to this,  I was trying to follow the same steps as in inbuilt `pipeline` and configure resolve item and apply mapping steps as shown in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Trainings are in DynamicsContact `Facet`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add more details about synchronization process? Is it default 'xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync' process provided from by Dynamics Connector?

Comment: Hi Artsem
No, its not default pipeline batch, I have created another batch pipeline to sync custom data from xconnect to CRM.
It synchronizes the trainings of a user.

Comment: Ok, it is difficult to suggest something because I don't know what steps you have before the 'Add Contact Model to xConnect Batch' one. But anyway, error says that you don't have an resolved which you try to put into butch.

Comment: I have added few more edits in the question, will it be useful for you to help me out?

Comment: Could you also add a screenshorts of `Read Contacts from xConnect` and `Resolve Dynamics Contact By Identifier` steps?

Comment: Kindly have a look and let me know if it is useful

Comment: What is the value if `Entity Name` field in `Resolve Dynamics Contact By Identifier` step?

Comment: It's the name of entity  from Crm i.e "im_performedtraining"

Comment: And, probably, latest question that I need to ask for preparing an answer... You said that you sync custom data from xConnect. Is it just a custom facet within an xDB contact?

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: Have you added the `Value Accessors Set` for your custom facet? if it is, could you share it?

Comment: added for Dynamics CRM same is for xConnect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few wrong thing in your implementation.

**Resolve Dynamics Contact By Identifier pipeline step:**

1. `Identifier Value Accessor` - This value accessor shoud be set for xConnect Contact, e.g.: `Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/xConnect/DynamicsContact/TrainingId`. This value accessor is used to get identificator for resolving entity in Dynamics CRM.
2. `Value Reader to Convert Identifier Value for Comparison` - This Value Reader is used to read value from Identifier object. If your training id is stored as a field in a facet, you don't need to set this reader.

[image: Resolve Dynamics Contact By Identifier]

Let's fix it first and then we will see what will happen else and extend the answer with further recommendations.

Comment: Changed the Identifier Value Accessor in Resolve Dynamics Contacts by Identifier and still it gives the same error.

Comment: Share please the latest batch execution log

Comment: It helped understand the pipeline process and the logic behind. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sujana, would need understanding from you on connector sync logic. While mapping contacts from SItecore to CRM, does the connector compares all the contacts available in CRM to check weather the contact needs to be created or updated? or the connector is just aware of the contacts that are being mapped initially with.